# Log Buckets from Google

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-logging

Is it possible to download a Log Storage (Log bucket) from Google Cloud Platform, specifically the one created by default? In case someone knows they can explain how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution for the question is you need to choose the required logs and then get the logs for the time period of 1 day to download them in JSON or CSV format.

Step1- From the logging console goto advanced filtering mode

Step2- To choose the log type use filtering query, for example

resource.type="audited_resource"
logName="projects/xxxxxxxx/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access"

resource.type="audited_resource"
logName="organizations/xxxxxxxx/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fpolicy"

Step3- You can download them as JSON and CSV format

If you have a huge number of audit logs generated per day then above one will not work out. So, you need to export logs to [Cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export?_ga=2.94560860.-1125633349.1607554198&_gac=1.254584698.1606866013.CjwKCAiA8Jf-BRB-EiwAWDtEGiZx8E1EC706e5fzci-fSFmZL2ySLxLL6cRsRnLHjVJ0qcVFAZi0GxoCj2QQAvD_BwE) and a big query for further analysis. Please note that cloud logging doesn’t charge to export logs but [destination charges](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export?_ga=2.94560860.-1125633349.1607554198&_gac=1.254584698.1606866013.CjwKCAiA8Jf-BRB-EiwAWDtEGiZx8E1EC706e5fzci-fSFmZL2ySLxLL6cRsRnLHjVJ0qcVFAZi0GxoCj2QQAvD_BwE#pricing) might apply.

Another option, you can use the following gcloud command to [download the logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#viewing_audit_logs).

gcloud logging read "logName : projects/Your_Project/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity" --project=Project_ID --freshness=1d >> test.txt

Comment: The problem is that I have to download the logs many times and they can be more than a million.

Comment: You need to export the log, for more information pls [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export?_ga=2.94560860.-1125633349.1607554198&_gac=1.254584698.1606866013.CjwKCAiA8Jf-BRB-EiwAWDtEGiZx8E1EC706e5fzci-fSFmZL2ySLxLL6cRsRnLHjVJ0qcVFAZi0GxoCj2QQAvD_BwE)